# Query for adding column from another table in a fast way

Tags: sql, oracle

I am somewhat of a novice when SQL comes, so need help for my problem as following (I have tried update but it is very slow)

I have a table A (with 6.5 mil records), I want to add a column (Y) to it with values from table B (with 2.5 mil records) with the condition for a (common) column X A.X = B.X

B doesn't have all the X values that A has.

Further, X does not a unique value, however for duplicate values of Y, X has also duplicate values

Meaning there will never be a case X=10,Y=5 and X=10,Y=15 (Y will have duplicate values as well)

Additional information may be relevant
I dont need to add all the values from Y only where A.X < 0 ( and A.X = B.X)

Answer (score 0):

1. Write an actual SELECT which would return what you need in the
   table. Regarding duplicates you can do "select distinct" to remove
   duplicates from the output.
2. Create a VIEW based on the select you
   wrote. You don't have to create a TABLE if you just need to 'share
   the select', chances are that view is more efficient for you and way
   more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you tried something like this

```
alter table A add( Y NUMBER); 

update A set Y = (select distinct Y from B where A.X = B.X)
where A.X < 0;
```

that is the simplest case.. and "slow" is relative 10millions rows isnt small. but maybe you need an index on B.X to prevent full table scans.  could be removed again later if desired.

Comment: Did you mean to select Y from B (not X)? And it seems you missed the part where the update should be made only when `A.X < 0`.

Comment: probably..  updated this answer now to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

First add the column `y` to table `a` (perhaps you did already).

Then, when you update a target table with data from another ("source") table, the `merge` statement is often better than `update`. It is easier to read and understand (and therefore to maintain), it is more flexible - you may have updates, inserts and deletes all in one statement, and sometimes it may be faster than (and it is never slower than) `update` and the other statements it replaces.

Something like this:

```
merge into a
  using (select distinct x, y from b where x < 0) g
  on (a.x = g.x)
when matched then update
  set a.y = g.y
```

Note that, as everyone else already pointed out, you must `select distinct` in a subquery `g` first; you can't update from table `b` directly.